# SKSpriteKit, detect non-transparency parts

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, sprite-kit

I am making a game in SKSpriteKit, I am trying to make a foreground object with this Image, http://minus.com/i/OQ0boloElnCr

if an object touches the non-transparency in the picture(the ceiling and rock paths), the object dies. 
Is it possible in Sprite kit to detect the ceiling, the non-transparency parts of the image