# XCode Spritekit, collision with non-transparent sections of an png

Tags: iphone, xcode, collision

I have the same problem like here: [SKSpriteKit, detect non-transparency parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089846/skspritekit-detect-non-transparency-parts/22019421#22019421)

My post is deleted from there. I don't know why, in other forums, THIS is a double post!!!
But ok, if you like that. Poor danny who still have not the answer!

Ok well, here comes the question again:
There are two png files with transparent areas. Like in the post of danny huang.
If they collide the "-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact" method fire.
But what we looking for is that they just collied with the non-transparent areas of the image.

Here is a small code snipped:

```
...
SKTexture *nyanTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"test.png"];
nyanTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
nyan = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:nyanTexture1];
nyan.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:nyan.size.height / 2];
nyan.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
nyan.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
...
nyan.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nyanKategorie;
nyan.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = worldKategorie | tunnelKategorie;
nyan.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldKategorie | tunnelKategorie;
...
WasserFallTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Wasserstrahl1.png"];
SKSpriteNode* tunnel1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:WasserFallTexture1];
tunnel1.position = CGPointMake( 0, y );
tunnel1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:tunnel1.size];
tunnel1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
tunnel1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = tunnelKategorie;
tunnel1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nyanKategorie;
...
[tunnel addChild:tunnel1];
```

I can do that without the nice engine of Spritekit. I implement it as well, but i want to know a way to do that with the SpriteKit engine.
I know that i can change the "SKPhysicsBody" type and areas, but i'm looking for a soloution witch can catch a collision between two png files non-transparent areas.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like actually seeing the physics bodies in action is what you need. There is a property on `SKView` called `showsPhysics`. Set that to `YES` and you can see the physics bodies of your sprites in action.